# Drag files from windows explorer to Total commander

Tags: total-commander

Is possible to move files from windows explorer to Total commander?

I use 64 bit version total commander.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drag and drop files from explorer to total commander you should not start total commander as an admin because you cannot drag and drop files from an elevated program (higher rights) to a non-elevated program, or vice versa. You should modify total commander executable file (TCUP.exe), right click on the file, properties, security tab, edit, and check the box allow for "full control" for every group or use name. [img][https://ibb.co/pz524CP[/img]](https://ibb.co/pz524CP%5B/img%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can drag and drop files from windows explorer with mouse to total commander.
You only have to keep <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed during the operation in order to move the files (and not copy them).

Comment: It is not working for me on windows 10.